# Join with tolerance in date POSIXCT in R

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have two dataframes D1 and D2 that I need to merge with a left join. The join must be done at the same time on 4 variables: X1, X2, X3 and X4. These variables are all 4 present in the two data frames. However, for the variable X4 it represents a date in POSIXCT format (the same format in D1 and D2) and I must attach it with the following tolerance: -1 minute in advance, and +5 minutes late.

left_join(D1,D2,..)

I am a beginner on R and I searched in the group but I did not find an answer already proposed! thank you for helping me

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag home page and in particular a complete minimal reproducible example including code and inputs using `dput` are needed for SO posts so that anyone else can use it in their answer.  At any rate, `sqldf` can do complex joins such as this one.  Search for that on SO.  Also the data.table package can do certain complex joins.

Comment: Okey, i'll chek this,  thanks for your answer

Comment: You might want to bring the time-value information from one data frame to another with `approx` (linear interpolation) rather than a join.  For example, if you have information in one data frame for time = 9:00, 9:10, 9:20, ... value = 31, 32, 39, ... you can use approx to calculate an interpolated value at 9:05 equal to 31.5.

Comment: The goal is to match the real bus trips D1 (realized) with the theoretical trips (D2) (each trip is defined by the 4 variables mentioned above: X1: trip_id
X2: service_id
X3:stop_name
X4: depature time) so it's a join I need

Comment: these 4 variables must match at the same time to match the bus run. except for X4 I need a tolerance because the real is always different from the theoretical

Comment: The fuzzyjoin package has a number of different ways of doing this sort of join so would definitely be worth looking at.